# pgRouting cannot find extension control file

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I am trying to use pgrouting on OS X. I installed the following:

```
brew install postgres
brew install postgis
brew install pgrouting
```

When I try to create the extension pgrouting I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/share/postgresql/extension/pgrouting.control": No such file or directory
```

Also when I list all installed extensions I only get the following:

```
\dx
                                     List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                             Description                             
---------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis | 2.1.5   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
(2 rows)
```

How to I have to install pgrouting in order to use it? 
I am on OS X 10.10.1

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have something like librouting.so in your

/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/bin folder

and if you have any script files in contrib of postgresql.

I'm guessing you may have a couple of PostgreSQL installs and it got installed into the wrong one.  Alternatively it installed an older version pre-2.0 which was installed with scripts.

I'm not a Mac User so my paths above may be completely wrong place to look

Comment: I don't have any files in the described folder of yours. I ended up installing it from source. This way it worked.